# Not able to configure endpoint keys in LUIS

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

How to publish in the new UI of Luis? The tenant id is not getting listed in my account. I have generated keys in the azure portal but not able to configure it in LUIS. Earlier we had a keys tab and we could add the key there. It seems they have changed it now. Any help on this?

[image: LUIS Image here]

Comment: are you saying that the http://www.luis.ai app previously had your keys and now doesn't (not due to any change you made) --- or are you saying you need to change one/all of the keys and the app is not allowing you to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you mean: there was previously a `My Keys` tab in LUIS.ai website.

This tab seems to have been removed, but you can still change your key inside your project, using `Publish App`: there is an item called `Assigned endpoint key`.

Based on the image you put in your question, I suppose you have found it. On my side it is successfully listing my Tenant IDs, then my subscriptions and keys so I am able to managed them.

If you are talking about creating a new key, it must be done from the Azure portal.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicolas. When I opened Azure portal simultaneously with the LUIS account, it worked.